# convert JSON Array to selected keys' JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, underscore.js

I have a JSON array as below:

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street":"201 S 4th St.",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
},
"hobbies":[
        {
          "books":"fiction",
          "sports":"football",
          "music":"rock"
        },

        {
          "books":"action",
          "sports":"cricket",
          "music":"jazz"
        },
        {
          "books":"action",
          "sports":"cricket",
          "music":"cool"
        },

]},{
"id":2,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kulas Light",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"phone": ["1-770-736-8031 x56442", "4087917884", "4089088939"],
"website": "hildegard.org",
"dept":[{"name":"divya", "address":"abc"},{"name":"divya1", "address":"abc1"}],
"hobbies":[
          {
            "books":"fiction",
            "sports":"football",
            "music":"rock"
          },

          {
            "books":"action",
            "sports":"cricket",
            "music":"jazz"
          },
          {
            "books":"action",
            "sports":"cricket",
            "music":"cool"
          },
]}]
```

I wanted to use only specific keys only in Hobbies key. Let's say I need only books and sports from Hobbies key. How can I do this in Nodejs?
The result should be like below:

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street":"201 S 4th St.",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
},
"hobbies":[
        {
          "books":"fiction",
          "sports":"football",

        },

        {
          "books":"action",
          "sports":"cricket",

        },
        {
          "books":"action",
          "sports":"cricket",

        },

] },{
"id":2,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kulas Light",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"phone": ["1-770-736-8031 x56442", "4087917884", "4089088939"],
"website": "hildegard.org",
"dept":[{"name":"divya", "address":"abc"},{"name":"divya1", "address":"abc1"}],
"hobbies":[
          {
            "books":"fiction",
            "sports":"football",

          },

          {
            "books":"action",
            "sports":"cricket",

          },
          {
            "books":"action",
            "sports":"cricket",

          },
]}].
```

Please note that this is just one example. my input is an array of JSON and the keys that I wanted to keep. keys for this example are "id", "name", "hobbies.books", "hobbies.sports"  etc.

Comment: No matter what, you need to learn how to access Array Elements and Object Properties. This comes down to a basic lack of understanding of JavaScript fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
hobbies.map(function(hobby) {
    return {
        books: hobby.books,
        sports: hobby.sports,
    }
});
```

What this is doing is creating a new array with values you specifically returned in the function.

If you're using ES6, you could also the fat-arrow syntax and other "shortcuts"

```
hobbies.map((hobby) => ({
    books: hobby.books,
    sports: hobby.sports,
});
```

Just run that any array that you want to manipulate. Assuming your object is named `json`, your function would look like:

```
const json = [] // your existing JSON

const filtered = json.map((obj) => ({
    id: obj.id,
    name: obj.name,
    hobbies: obj.hobbies.map((hobby) => ({
        books: hobby.books,
        sports: hobby.sports,
    })),
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that I don't know the key name is hobbies. it could be anything stored in my variable. So I need the generic solution where I have my JSON array in one variable and another variable or array contains values hobbies.books and hobbies.sports

Comment: How is it being determined what keys you need? Is that something you made up or is there an API you're following?

Comment: Yes, I have an external API that gives me json data and based on user selection of keys, I have to show that data only

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using node, I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. So you could use something like the lodash `pick` function, alongside `map`. For example:

```
const filteredHobbies = theObject.hobbies.map(item => _.pick(item, ['books', 'sports']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can carve out the hobbies array and then:

```
for(var h of hobbies) {
    delete h.music;
}
```

The final code could look like something:

```
var hob = object.hobbies;
for(var h of hob) {
    delete h.music;
}
object.hobbies = hob;
```